# SAS IT Mode controllers and SAS Expanders

Tags: zfs, sas, truenas

Lots of semi-related posts, but none that address this scenario.

I picked up an LSI SAS1064E-IR based HP Controller. I flashed it with an -IT firmware, and things look somewhat ok. Except that I have a SAS Expander in this system so that I can get more than 4 devices on this controller. The SAS utility in the card says it can support up to 24 devices.

However, when its connected to the SAS Expander, no devices are detected.

There are several articles siting various controllers to use which can be flashed to run in IT mode, so that targets are presented in a JBOD fashion, mostly for ZFS support under FreeNAS installations.

My 12bay server chassis requires that I use the expander due to the miniSAS interfaces on the back of the drive back plane. Due to space limitations in the case, I can only use 1 low profile adapter, then the expander is needed.

So, can anyone confirm that the controllers they have used in IT mode have been successfully used with SAS Expanders?

Answer (score 1):

The controller type (IT or IR) shouldn't matter. SAS expanders can be used with RAID controllers and SAS HBAs.

Comment: Well, in this case it does seem to matter. I updated the firmware for 1068E (even though its a 1064E) Dual vs Single connector. Perhaps that is the cause of my woe ? I was unable to locate an IT firmware specifically for the SAS1064E controller. Since they are part of the same family, 106xE ... I figured it would not make a big difference. The SAS utility correctly reports that it is a 1064E.

Perhaps someone reading knows of one ?

Comment: Try to go back to the original firmware intended for the device you HAVE.